# Can my landlord legally not let me do my anmeldung in Germany?

Tags: germany, residential-lease

I really need to do my anmeldung so I can start working and get health insurance in Germany now (during corona). I moved out of a youth hostel once it shut down and me and two others found a room for rent which is sort of a hotel that had been converted to an apartment during corona, since they lost their customers. The landlord says anmeldung is not possible here, but I was wondering if that is fair, since we are paying to be here, and it is now basically impossible for us to get our anmeldung without moving and paying somewhere else (or even double paying). I can’t generate income without my anmeldung.

Comment: "sort of a hotel that had been converted to an apartment during corona". This is the salient point. Has it actually been (legally) converted to an apartment or is merely that the hotel is offering extended accommodation periods. Do you have a rental contract?

Comment: anmeldung = residency registration, a distinctively Germany bureaucratic process. https://mag.n26.com/how-to-register-your-address-in-germany-aka-do-the-anmeldung-a62fad5d429

Comment: @ohwilleke Most European countries have such systems. It supplies the city important planing information ; simplifies a passport application ; automatic sending of a voters card before an election. So it has its benifits.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Fair enough. The primary purpose of the comment was to define the German language term for future readers, which is difficult because there isn't a good exact counterpart in English since it is far more of a big deal than, for example, a voter registration and most common law countries disaggregate the role it serves into multiple filings.

Answer (score 3):

No, they can't. They are required by law to issue a **Einzugsbestätigung** when your indended stay is longer than 3 months when staying in a hostel or pension or another form of temporary accommodation.

The rule for **temporary residence** (up to 3 months) have many exceptions

- Youth Hostel are exempted
- Hotels, Pensions have a simplified registration (Hotel registration)

For **long term residence** in  Hostel, Pension etc.  (**everything** more than 3 months), the standard rules apply

- registration after 3 months plus 14 days at the latest
- may be done earlier, if the extended stay exceeds 3 months

This sample assumes the person is **not** registered elsewere in Germany.

For those who **are** registered elsewhere in Germany

- 6 months apply instead of 3 months

A **Einzugsbestätigung** (Confirmation of moving in) must be issued by the landlord when registering.

Should the landlord refuse to issue a **Einzugsbestätigung**, you are **required** to report this to registry office **immediately** to avoid paying a fine.

In pratical terms, you should go to the office personally and tell them that you want to register but landlord refuse to issue a **Einzugsbestätigung**.

When moving a **permanent** residence, registration within 14 days is required.

---

> [Die „Hotelmeldepflicht“](https://www.rehm-verlag.de/verwaltung/aktuelle-beitraege-zum-pass-ausweis-und-melderecht/die-hotelmeldepflicht/)
> **3. Abgrenzung zur allgemeinen Meldepflicht**
> ...
> Allerdings greift für eine Beherbergungsstätte diese allgemeine Meldepflicht lediglich dann ein, wenn eine der beiden folgenden Fallgruppen vorliegt:
> **Fallgruppe 1:**
> Die aufgenommene Person ist nicht für eine Wohnung im Inland gemeldet **und ihr Aufenthalt überschreitet die Dauer von drei Monaten**.
>
> Dann muss sie sich bei der Meldebehörde ganz regulär anmelden und zwar binnen zwei Wochen, nachdem der Zeitraum von drei Monaten überschritten wurde. (Fall des [§ 29 Abs. 1 Satz 2 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0274)). Eine Anmeldung schon vor Ablauf der genannten Zeitgrenzen ist möglich, sofern von vornherein ein darüber hinausgehender Aufenthalt beabsichtigt ist.
> ...
>
> > **3. Differentiation from the general reporting obligation**
> > ...
> > However, this general reporting obligation only applies to an accommodation facility if one of the two following groups of cases applies:
> > **Case group 1:**
> > The admitted person is not registered for an apartment in Germany **and their stay exceeds three months**.
> >
> > Then they have to register with the registration authority in the normal way, within two weeks after the period of three months has been exceeded.  (Case of [Section 29 Paragraph 1 Sentence 2 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0274)).  It is possible to register before the specified time limits have expired, provided that a longer stay is planned from the outset.
> > ...

> [Meldegesetz – Einzugsbestätigung](https://www.finanztip.de/meldegesetz/) 
> **Weigert sich Ihr Vermieter** oder Wohnungsgeber, Ihnen die Bestätigung auszustellen, **müssen Sie dies umgehend der zuständigen Meldebehörde mitteilen** ([§ 19 Abs. 2 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0201)). Nur so laufen Sie nicht Gefahr, ein Bußgeld zahlen zu müssen. Denn wer seinen Pflichten nicht nachkommt, *riskiert ein Bußgeld von bis zu 1.000 Euro* ([§ 54 Abs. 2 Nr. 1, Abs. 3 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0588)).
>
> > **If your landlord or the landlord refuses** to issue you the confirmation, **you must notify the competent registration authority immediately** ([Section 19 (2) BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0201)).  This is the only way you do not run the risk of having to pay a fine.  Because anyone who does not meet his obligations *risks a fine of up to 1,000 euros* ([Section 54, Paragraph 2, No. 1, Paragraph 3 BMG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0588)).

---

**Sources**:

- [Die „Hotelmeldepflicht“ | rehm. Beste Antwort](https://www.rehm-verlag.de/verwaltung/aktuelle-beitraege-zum-pass-ausweis-und-melderecht/die-hotelmeldepflicht/)

  - [Section 29 - Special registration requirement for commercial accommodations](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0274)
- [Meldegesetz – Muss ich dem Amt eine Einzugsbestätigung vorlegen? - Finanztip](https://www.finanztip.de/meldegesetz/)

  - [Section 19 - Cooperation by the supplier of the residence](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0201)
  - [Section 54 - Provisions on administrative fines](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0588)